# How should I use 'Google Chat REST API' to list spaces?

Tags: google-api

I'm developing some productivity app for test. It will integrate Google Drive and Google Chat via REST API. But I'm newbie at this so I decided to list files and messages in Google Drive and Chat for practice. Google Drive works as expected but Google Chat is not.

For this goal, I've referenced these documents.

- Google Cloud

  - [Create a Google Cloud project](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project)
  - Enable Google Workspace APIs
- Set up auth

  - [Configure the OAuth consent screen and choose scopes](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent)
  - Create access credentials
- Google Drive API

  - [Guides - Quickstarts, Javascript](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js)
  - Reference - Method: drives.list
- Google Chat API

  - [Guides - Call the REST API](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides)
  - Guides - Authenticate as a user
  - Guides - List spaces
  - Reference - Method: spaces.list

So, I did these.

- Prepare 2 Google accounts.

  - Business account (which has `Google Workspace`, organization, and real data)
  - Personal account (where the testing app created.)
- Do things at Google Cloud (`Personal account`)

  - Create new Project
  - Set to use the `Google Drive API` and `Google Chat API`
  - Create new App (or submit the app informations like consent, scope, test user, etc)
  - Create new `OAuth 2.0 Client ID` (which has URIs for javascript)
- Create simple Web Application for test

  - Mainly, refer `Guides - Quickstarts, Javascript` document.
  - Set the `CLIENT_ID` from above
  - Set the proper `SCOPE`s
  - Login as `Business account` and allow this testing app
  - Call `gapi.client.drive.drives.list({...})` (and this works)
  - Call `gapi.client.chat.spaces.list({...})` (this does not work)

Below is the error message of request and it's response.

```
GET https://content-chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces 404 (Not Found)
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Google Chat app not found. To create a Chat app, you must turn on the Chat API and configure the app in the Google Cloud console.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "To turn on the Google Chat API, go to the Google Chat API page in the Google Cloud console and click Enable.",
            "url": "..."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "To configure your Chat app, go to the Google Chat API Configuration tab in the Google Cloud console.",
            "url": "..."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "To learn about creating Google Chat apps, visit the documentation.",
            "url": "..."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Error says 'Google Chat app not found' but the account is using Google Chat and has spaces and messages. If the reason why this error occurs is that the app is not created on `Business account` then the fact that Google Drive API works does not make sense to me.

Also, the `Try this method` in `Reference - Method: spaces.list` document works well exactly same as I'm trying to do.

Can I get help? Am I missing anything?